# Change git branch's root, retainig older commit as branch HEAD?

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

Forgive me if I've phrased it incorrectly, but what I have is `master` and `master-variant` where the latter is a variant of the generic product that I'm working on. It contains additional files and some changed files.

The problem is that I'm creating this "in reverse", because I started out with the variant and am now in need of this new generic "root" because I will add other new variants branched from it.

So I started out with the original variant in `master` and created a branch `master-variant` for the current state, without any changes (i.e. it points to the same commit as `master`).

Then I modified the contents of `master` to make it "generic", i.e. removed everything variant-specific and commited it there. In this state, `master` has a new commit compared to the commit that `master-variant` points to.

But I want it to appear as if I started out with the generic `master` (the last commit there) and then branched `master-variant` off it, and added the variant-specific stuff, i.e. the state of the previous commit in `master`.

I'll try to illustrate. What I have is this (m = `master`, v = `master-variant`):

```
m0---m1---m2---m3 (changes to create generic variant)
           \
            v1 (just a new ref to m2)
```

Note that `m0`..`m2` are in the `master` branch, but their *contents* are the original variant that I now want in a branch instead.

I want to change this so it would instead look like this:

```
m0---m1---m2---m3 (same as above, the generic variant)
                \
                 v1 (same content as "v1" above, which is also the same content as "m2" in both illustrations)
```

How can I achieve this?

My first thought was to use `git rebase`, but I fail to see how that would be possible, since what it does is to replay commits while I need to replay the *reverse* of a commit, i.e. the reverse of the `m3` commit.

I guess I could stash the `m2`/`v1` state, delete the `master-variant` branch, switch to `master` (i.e. commit `m3`), pop the stashed state and commit it to a new `master-variant` branch.

But is there a more direct approach?

I guess in short, what I really want is to create a branch that contains the state of a historic commit, but have that branch rooted at HEAD (not at the historic commit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminder: commits *are* snapshots of the file state.  The commits themselves form the commit graph, while the *branch names* are simply labels that identify (point to) a specific commit.

You said that in your diagram, `v1` is literally a *reference to* commit `m2`.  That is, it's not already a separate commit of its own.  So what you really have is:

```
C0--C1--C2   <-- v1
          \
           C3   <-- master
```

where `v1` and `master` are labels (names) that point into the graph formed by the commits themselves, which are `C0` through `C3`.  The graph you describe yourself as wanting adds a new commit `C4` whose contents match those of `C2` but whose parent (historic commit just behind itself) is C3:

```
C0--C1--C2    C4   <-- v1
          \  /
           C3   <-- master
```

Given that this is the case, you have two relatively easy options.  One is to go into Git's so-called *plumbing commands* and use a command that makes a new commit, giving it a specific saved snapshot and set of parents.  The new commit is your `C4`.  Then, having copied `C2` to `C4`, you would move the name `v1` to point to `C4`.  The two specific Git commands for this are:

```
hash=$(git commit-tree -p master v1^{tree} -F /tmp/message)
```

where `/tmp/message` contains the commit log message you'd like to use.  Note too that some shells may interpret the `^` or `{` characters; if so, quote them.  You can then run `git log $hash` to verify that the commit looks right.  Then, if you're currently "on" branch `v1`:

```
git reset $hash
```

will adjust the `v1` label.  (Be sure your index and work-tree are clean, i.e., that there is nothing uncommitted to save.)  If not:

```
git branch -v v1 $hash
```

will adjust the `v1` label.

Alternatively, consider that *reverting* the commit `C3` would back out its changes and leave you with a new commit that matches `C2`.  So you could:

```
git checkout v1
git merge --ff-only master
```

which would produce:

```
C0--C1--C2
          \
           C3   <-- v1 (HEAD), master
```

Then you would just run:

```
git revert HEAD
```

to make a new commit that backs out the difference between `C2` and `C3`, giving you a new commit `C4`:

```
C0--C1--C2    C4   <-- v1 (HEAD)
          \  /
           C3   <-- master
```

and again you're done.

If you had many commits to revert—i.e., if you wanted:

```
C0--C1--C2   <- v1
          \
           C3--C4--C5   <-- master
```

to become:

```
C0--C1--C2            C6   <- v1
          \          /
           C3--C4--C5   <-- master
```

then the `git commit-tree` method is less work (though you can still use `git revert`, you just need `-n` in this case while reverting `C5`, `C4`, and `C3`, or a subsequent `git rebase -i` where you squash together all the new commits).  In other words, `git commit-tree` is exactly the tool that achieves:

> ... what I really want is to create a branch that contains the state of a historic commit, but have that branch rooted at HEAD (not at the historic commit).

Comment: Great detail and explanation. Thanks! Read up on `git commit-tree` and tried that first, but got an error "fatal: 007a[snip]d8f is not a valid 'tree' object". Not sure why that didn't work. (Ideas?) But I then tried the revert approach and got the result I want. Problem solved. Thumbs up!

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake above (will fix it) - you need to specify a `^{tree}` suffix as `git commit-tree` doesn't resolve the commit to its tree.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to find docs about `^{tree}` but failed. Would appreciate a hint where to look. General reference syntax?

Comment: Found docs about `^{tree}` here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects
But I think I'll have to read a bit more to fully grasp the relevance in this context. Any additional links or explanations are welcome, of course.

Comment: See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions). The `^{...}` suffix syntax directs the internal revision parser to attempt to convert the object-so-far (as named by whatever came before the suffix) to an object of the given type. There is a shorthand with no type that means "dereference a tag".